# After installing Homebrew I get `zsh: command not found: brew`

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew, zsh

```
➜  ~ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
-e:77: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040677
It appears Homebrew is already installed. If your intent is to reinstall you
should do the following before running this installer again:
    ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
The current contents of /usr/local are bin CODEOFCONDUCT.md etc git lib Library LICENSE.txt munki README.md sbin share .git .github .gitignore
➜  ~ brew install maven
zsh: command not found: brew
```

Answer (score 634):

I had a similar issue on macOS Big Sur (11.0.1). In my case homebrew was saved in `/opt/homebrew/`, and not in `/usr/local/...`.

So I added

`export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH`

to `.zshrc` file in my home directory, and the ZSH shell was able to find the brew command.

Comment: `export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH` it helps, but how did you know that you have it there?
and `$PATH` does this mean a new folder? 

I get this steps in terminal:
```Add Homebrew to your PATH in /Users/admin/.zprofile:
    echo 'eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)' >> /Users/admin/.zprofile
    eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)
```

Comment: The path was shown in the terminal after Homebrew was done with the installation on my machine. '$PATH' just means that this new path will be added to the variable called PATH, known by the zsh shell. However this syntax is standard for bash.

Comment: hi where could I find `.zshrc` or that so called home directory? thank you

Comment: Either open a complete new terminal, you should start in the home directory, or if you somewhere in another directory, you can find it by entering `cd ~`.

Comment: That was the exact problem for me. My homerbew was installed in /opt/homebrew and not in /usrl/local

Comment: Quick tip, use `source ~/.zshrc` to make any changes to that file come into effect. Else, close and re-open your terminal.

Comment: If you are missing the file `.zshrc` in home `~` (e.g there is only `zsh_sessions` and `zsh_history`) simply create that file (`touch .zshrc`) and paste suggested export.

Comment: Down in answers I demonstrated @Spindizzy `answer step-by-step terminally speaking`

Comment: what should add instead $PATH

Comment: If you have installed homebrew recently, you may add export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin/brew:$PATH to your .zshrc file

Answer (score 522):

### for this error `zsh: command not found: brew`

1. Make sure you've installed Brew, with this (wait until it's done installing)
   (Edit: added ending quote to the end)

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

2. Then follow **NEXT STEPS** shown on the command line, it should show something like this :

```
==> Next steps:
- Add Homebrew to your PATH in /Users/$USER/.zprofile:
    echo 'eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)' >> /Users/$USER/.zprofile
    eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)
```

3. Copy and paste the first line on the same terminal window, then hit enter :

```
echo 'eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)' >> /Users/$USER/.zprofile
```

4. Then Copy and paste the last line on the same terminal window, then hit enter :

```
eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)
```

Finally, you should be able to use `brew help` and if that works, it means that brew was installed properly and running from `ZSH`.

Comment: This Works in Ubuntu 21.04 with linuxbrew, after thar, don't forget to signout or restart. thanks brother for this. for linux user. use this "eval $(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)" and add this to ~/.zprofile

Comment: This is exactly what I had to do and what it told me to do, but I refrained from pasting those commands as they showed up only on my machine on running the install command from their official website for HomeBrew installation, while it didn't have a second step in the installation process on my friend's machine as new as mine (A day old). haha my bad. If anyone else went down the same route, I feel ya! 
And, this answer literally told me: "Do what you read in the console output of your terminal. Don't question. It at the least won't turn a time bomb on" Thanks @Jonathan Sanchez

Comment: after running these commands it works fine, but when I close the the terminal and reopen it says ```-bash: brew: command not found```

Comment: For me on a Mac, after running step 1, I'm able to use brew to install node ```brew install node```

Comment: Still worked for me at May 2020.

Comment: I'm kind of annoyed that you have to run the steps to install it into your PATH separately. Typically anytime you install something from a package manager, it automatically loads it into your PATH for you -- the homebrew maintainers deciding NOT to do that violates the principle of least surprise imho.

Comment: @Keval run the above steps again, this time adding it to your bash profile

echo 'eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)' >> /Users/$USER/.bash_profile

Answer (score 117):

Edit `.zshrc` file :

```
nano .zshrc
```

The following should be enough :

```
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"
```

###### Before 2023

And add this to the beginning of the file :

```
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH
```

Save and run :

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

*Tested and working **Apple M1** / **M1 PRO** and **M2** / **M2 PRO** / **M3*** / **M3 PRO**

*Macbook Air **M2***

Comment: After all, don't forget to run: `source ~/.zshrc`

Comment: Finally! The only answer that worked!

Comment: Do someboy have an Idea why this come on the first place ? I have to do that every time I'm opening vs code

Comment: that's working for apple m2 macbook. thanks.

Comment: working on m2 Mac mini, thanks!

Comment: Thanks it's working for me in Macbook Air M2.

Answer (score 93):

**Update 2024**

```
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: This worked for the me, the selected answer above did not.

Comment: specifically, homebrew is picking a different directory depending on if you're running an intel processor `/usr/local` or an apple processor `/opt/homebrew`: https://docs.brew.sh/Installation

Answer (score 73):

Here are the steps I did...

1.Install homebrew

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

2.Run `brew help` and see if it's working... If it showing an error "zsh: command not found: brew" follow along.

3. Change the path to:

```
echo 'eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)' >> /Users/"YOUR USER NAME"/.zprofile
```

Remember to change the "USER NAME" with yours,
Then type in:

```
eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)
```

Once successfully running these command type "brew help" to see if everything went ok.

Comment: this worked for MacOS Monterey for those looking

Comment: This works for mac OS

Comment: This worked for me in Monterey 12.2.1

Comment: This worked for Mac OS 12.5

Comment: Worked for Ventura 13.1

Comment: Would be easier to just do `echo 'eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)' >> ~/.zprofile`. That way you don't need to get the username right.

Answer (score 64):

Homebrew has been installed on you computer. You need to modify your PATH like this:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

or execute `brew` from its origin:

```
/usr/local/bin/brew install maven
```

Comment: just to complement: to make that change to PATH a *permanent* one, you should insert that `export ...` command into your local `~/.zshrc`

Comment: The `.zshrc` should already have this line in it and you would just need to remove the `#` to uncomment and restart your shell.

Answer (score 28):

I got the same issue after installing Homebrew in my MacBook (macOS Big Sur V 11.0.1).

After installation, in the console it says what should be done:

> ```
> ==> Next steps:
> - Add Homebrew to your PATH in /Users/USER/.zprofile:
>   echo 'eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)' >> /Users/USER/.zprofile
>   eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)
> - Run `brew help` to get started
> ```

Executing those two commands, in order, will add the brew command into the PATH:

```
echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /Users/USER/.zprofile

eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

Comment: Solved my problem.

Comment: This worked on macos Monterey

Answer (score 16):

Just add `export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH` in your home directory

Restart if needed or just reopen your terminal

Comment: I'm using macOS 14.0 M1 and running this command in a terminal solved the issue for me `eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)`

Answer (score 11):

I will just demonstrate the answer from @Spindizzy terminally speaking:

```
cd ~ | ls -a
touch .zshrc // if file .zshrc doesn't exists we create it
vim .zshrc
```

Paste `PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH` there, save file and **restart terminal**.

Vim helper:

```
1. press "i" to interactive mode in vim, paste:
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH
2. press "esc" type ":wq" and hit enter
```

Answer (score 9):

make sure install brew first

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I added the following line to ~/.zshrc

```
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

Answer (score 6):

In `fish` shell on Apple M1, I had to add `/opt/homebrew/bin` to the `fish_user_paths` global env. I had to do this manually because `set -U fish_user_paths /opt/homebrew/bin $fish_user_paths` got

> set: Universal variable 'fish_user_paths' is shadowed by the global variable of the same name.

Comment: As of fish 3.2.0, released in March 2021 `fish_add_path /opt/homebrew/bin` should be enough

Answer (score 6):

Basically your homebrew is saved in /opt/homebrew/, and not in /usr/local/.... path

Open .bash_profile in your home directory and add :

```
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH
```

and restart the terminal. You will have it up and running.

Answer (score 6):

may be you have followed this step from homebrew homepage.

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

so may your system not able to allocate path so follow below steps.

```
sudo nano /etc/paths
```

paste

```
/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH
```

save and close

Answer (score 5):

This morning i too faced the same issue. The problem is path for homebrew is not set correctly.

Follow below steps

1.install homebrew correctly. In the terminal type below cmd.

/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

2. set the path in your .zshrc file in terminal type

   open ~/.zshrc

   In .zshrc file add the path like below

   export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
3. In terminal type source ~/.zshrc

   and your done.

Answer (score 4):

When installing, brew has this -NEXT STEPS console log when is needed to include its path to bash.

run the followed steps:

```
`echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /Users/YOUR_USER/.zprofile`

`eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"`
```

Answer (score 3):

Go to the official [Homebrew site](https://brew.sh/).

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Next steps:

```
test -d ~/.linuxbrew && eval $(~/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)
test -d /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew && eval $(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)
test -r ~/.bash_profile && echo "eval \$($(brew --prefix)/bin/brew shellenv)" >>~/.bash_profile
echo "eval \$($(brew --prefix)/bin/brew shellenv)" >>~/.profile
```

Try: `brew install hello`

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using zsh, you need to add the PATH to your .zshrc file:

`vim ~/.zshrc`

Add:

```
export BREW_HOME="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:$BREW_HOME"
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried:

```
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH
```

but it didn't work.

I researched the problem and realized that the above code works for only Apple chip Macs and not Intel chip Macs.

I edited the code, since my Mac is Intel-based, using:

1. In the Finder, open/edit the `.zshrc` file or create one if you cannot find it.
2. Paste this code:

   ```
    export PATH=/usr/local/homebrew/bin:$PATH
   ```

It should work.

Answer (score 3):

For the latest version as of 6-oct-2022...

==> Next steps:

- Run these three commands in your terminal to add Homebrew to your PATH:

  echo '# Set PATH, MANPATH, etc., for Homebrew.' >> /Users/tusharkhatri/.zprofile

  echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /Users/tusharkhatri/.zprofile

  eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
- Run brew help to get started
- Further documentation:
  https://docs.brew.sh

Answer (score 2):

It help me. Just run follow command:

```
echo '# Set PATH, MANPATH, etc., for Homebrew.' >> /Users/gureenkov56/.zprofile
echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /Users/gureenkov56/.zprofile
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

Answer (score 1):

might be late, but surely helpful. you have to install brew on first thing. just run the below command to do that:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're on WSL2 make sure to follow the final linux [installation instructions](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-on-Linux#install) for linuxbrew.

```
test -d ~/.linuxbrew && eval $(~/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)test -d /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew && eval $(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)
test -r ~/.bash_profile && echo "eval \$($(brew --prefix)/bin/brew shellenv)" >>~/.bash_profile
echo "eval \$($(brew --prefix)/bin/brew shellenv)" >>~/.profile
```

Comment: For me, even following the installation instructions, it was not sufficient. Every time I restart my terminal, I got brew was not found. What I did is $ touch .bash_profile, then $ cp .profile .bash_profile and restart WSL2. That's how I solve my issues.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Ubuntu and Arch Linux. I solved this problem by adding the path of the bin folder of brew to the `.zshrc` file.

The path to my brew installation bin directory is `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin`

Add following line to the `~/.zshrc` file 
`export PATH=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH`

After this do open a new terminal and the brew command will be available.

Answer (score 1):

I just did `echo 'eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> ~/.zshrc as I'm using oh-my-zsh`. After doing this should be able to use brew.

Answer (score 1):

To your `.zshrc` file, add the path to your `homebrew/bin`, wherever that might be. In my case, `homebrew` was installed in my home directory.
Add:

```
export PATH="/<path-to-homebrew-directory>/bin:$PATH"
```

Restart your terminal for it to pick up the changes to your `.zshrc`

Answer (score 1):

**Solution for Ubuntu 20.04**

1. After installing brew with:

   `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`
2. and ran what it says after (this did nothing for me just added lines to `.zprofile` every time i ran it):

   `echo 'eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /home/blcuser/.zprofile`

   `eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"`
3. BEFORE closing that terminal `copy` the output of:

   `echo $PATH`
4. Should be similar to this:

`/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`

What we need is the `path to brew` which is this part of the previews path (for you might be a different path)

`/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin`

5. Open `NEW` terminal and try to build the whole first path with:

Should be like: `<brew_path>:$PATH`

For me was this: `echo /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin:$PATH`

Should output the first whole path we output on `4.`

6. Open `.zshrc` file (mine is on `home` hidden file)
7. At the beginning of the `.zshrc` file add what we build on `5.`:

   `export PATH=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin:$PATH`
8. Save and restart terminals
9. Check that is working with:

   `brew doctor`

You should be set and brew should be started always with new terminals by default.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's not so obvious but in addition to the above steps, check your `.zshprofile` is not corrupted with any extraneous quotation marks. You should also close all terminal instances.

Answer (score 1):

**16.11.2022 - Update**
During brew installation I got multiple lines informing me about where brew will be installed. For me terminal said:

```
This script will install:
...
/usr/local/Homebrew
```

So path I needed was the last one. Steps to fix the issue:

1. Edit `.zshrc` file. Type:

   `nano ~/.zshrc`
2. Add line in the editor:

   `export PATH=/usr/local/homebrew/bin:$PATH`
3. Hit `Control+X` to Exit the editor, `Y` to accept the changes and `return` to accept where file is going to be saved.

After all you need to refresh the terminal you use. You can either close the process of it and open or type:

`source ~/.zshrc`

That's it! Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following setup then you will be ready to use brew

Run unintsall script :-

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"
```

Set Git Compression :- `git config --global core.compression 0`

Set Git buffer size :- `git config --global http.postBuffer 1048576000`

Run installation script :-
`/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"`

Answer (score 0):

You should add both `/opt/homebrew/bin` and `/opt/homebrew/sbin` to `$PATH` env.

export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:$PATH

for quick, run command

`echo export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin >> ~/.zshrc`

then run `brew doctor` to checking