# Macbook M1 chip fixing zsh: command not found: brew error

Tags: macos, homebrew

I'm trying to using `brew install sourcery` command but I getting ***zsh: command not found: brew*** error!

I'm installed homebrew with using bellow command:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

is there any way to fix this problem on the Macbook with M1 chip?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [After installing Homebrew I get \`zsh: command not found: brew\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36657321/after-installing-homebrew-i-get-zsh-command-not-found-brew)

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

> export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"

Answer (score 3):

Run next commands one by one:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"

echo 'eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)' >> /Users/$USER/.zprofile

eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)

brew help
```